# Python script stops working after packaging with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script that basically sends a live screen share stream to my server. I run it through PyCharm and it works as expected, however when i package it using PyInstaller it seems to be stuck at the while true block. In task manager, the exe file keeps opening processes infinitely, consuming more and more RAM. I'm not sure what's the cause of that, since it doesnt do that if i run it from PyCharm. And the best part is, no error is getting logged to the console. It just prints this (in the following order):

hello
Connected to server
connected to sio
confirmed func
while loop

But when i run the python file on Pycharm it spams the console with print statments as it should.

Anyways, here's some more technical data:

Python version: 3.11.3
PyInstaller version: 5.11.0
opencv-python version: 4.7.0.72
numpy version: 1.24.3
pyscreenshot version: 3.1
socketio version: 5.8.0

Heres the script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import socketio
import threading

SERVER_URL = ''

sio = socketio.Client()


@sio.event
def connect():
    print('Connected to server')


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('Disconnected from server')


print("hello")


def send_frame_to_server(frame):
    print("frame cap func confirmed")

    _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    frame_bytes = jpeg.tobytes()

    print("emitting frame..")
    sio.emit('frame', frame_bytes)
    print("emitted frame")


def capture_and_send_frames():
    print("confirmed func")
    while True:
        print("while loop")

        screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
        print("screenshot")
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        print("captured screen")
        send_frame_to_server(frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sio.connect(SERVER_URL)
    print("connected to sio")
    threading.Thread(target=capture_and_send_frames()).start()
    print("ran func")
```

I tried running the function in a thread, didn't work. I tried running PyInstaller --onefile, also had the same results.

Comment: Just a heads-up: `target=capture_and_send_frames()` should be `target=capture_and_send_frames` without the parentheses. You're passing the name of a function to `target`, not calling that function.

Comment: Nice profile picture. You included your threaded code, can you also provide unmodified code?

Comment: @doneforaiur thanks lol, the unmodified code is pretty much the same but then i just call the function like normal without threading. both work in py but none work after packaging

Comment: So there's no "screenshot" output in the terminal. It seems like this problem; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883813/pyscreenshot-as-imagegrab-doesnt-work-after-compiling-with-pyinstaller-to-exe Can you check?

Comment: @doneforaiur That seems to have done the trick! Thank you so much.